# aurelia-redux-immutable - recommended way to subscribe?

Tags: redux, immutability, aurelia, subscribe

I am employing the aurelia-redux-immutable package in my project. It's great, the only thing is that everything you need is hooked up to the view model - EXCEPT subscribe. What is the recommended way of subscribing with this tool?

Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are dependent on the state property change notification events in the local class to know if/what changed.